# Reactjs fetching data from backend outside local network

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, frontend, connection, backend

The issue I have is as follows,

I have a reactjs frontend and a asp.net core backend, I am trying to get data from the backend, by fetching, when accessing my frontend from outside my local network. My frontend is hosted using IIS on port 80, and portforwarded this port using ngrok. I am able to access my frontend now from outside my local network, but I am not able to fetch data from the backend, mainly because I am not sure where to make the calls to specifically.

The backend is listening on port 5000 and the frontend is making fetch requests to this port along with the target ip adress. But it can't connect. I have tried making calls using my public ip, local ip or just 0.0.0.0. I need it to work on my own pc, local network and outside my local network.

This might be a stupid issue that is easily solved, but I don't really have a clue where to begin here, hopefully someone can help me a bit further trying to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you call an API from your SPA (react app), the request is triggered from the browser showing your app.

So, when you load your port-forwarded app from outside your network, your browser, which is outside your network, is trying to call your API which is inside.

You have 2 possible solutions:

1/ port-forward the port 5000 of your router to the internal IP address (and port) of your server (e.g 192.168.1.10). Then from your React app, make the requests to your public IP address with the port (e.g 81.xx.xx.xx:5000)

2/ or, as you're already using Ngrok, install Ngrok on your server to get a direct URL to its port (`ngrok http 5000`) and make your requests to that URL